ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' while loading a model
I want to load and open a file so I can check an AI model. However, my code is throwing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' even though I'm not using sklearn. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?
My code is below:
import pickle
modell = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))


The model you are trying to load obviously uses sklearn. This makes sense when you are trying to load a machine learning model, as sklearn is a really popular library.
Install sklearn with pip install scikit-learn
